# Possible to open .jnt file type in browser?

Tags: browser-addons

Is there a browser plugin or other download that allows .jnt files to be viewed?

Why:

JNT files are used mainly for tablets, where people handwrite notes and save the file (pretty much an image of the note) as a jnt. Software exists to view and edit these for windows pc's as well. A client of mine wants to be able to view these in the browser, so as to avoid having to download the file in order to view it. I figured the only way that is possible is if there was a plugin to allow that to happen.

Comment: It is very puzzling how anyone can imagine a computer being able to display a file without  downloading it!

Comment: I'm concerned this puzzles you so much - as you don't need the entirety of the file in order to display it.

Comment: Also, as I understand it (having the same question myself), it's not the fact of downloading itself what the problem is, but the implicitness of it: the browser should not ask me things, just download and show it. In fact, I'd also like a way (e.g. dbl-clicking) to edit it right from the browser. (Probably yes, an extension is needed for that, which I couldn't find yet.)